# Delphi ScaleBy bugs (Vcl.ComCtrls.pas) - scales twice (squared) and other problems

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

Delphi 10.1 Berlin seems to have widely  defective `ScaleBy`.
It looks like Vcl.ComCtrls.pas has a bunch of scaling bugs. Has anyone fixed it?

Controls on PageControl are double scaled. Checkbox boxes and radio buttons are not scaled. Statusbars seem to be scaled by Scaleby but not scaled by DPI.

When font scale set in Windows 7 is 125% scaling also breaks and seems to go to 125% * Scale

The PageControl problem seems to be in VCL.ComCtrls.pas, new fn `TPageControl.ChangeScale` that calls its inherited method `CustomTabsheet.ChangeScale`. So everything on a tabsheets gets `ChangeScale` twice.

Comment: I can't confirm this (Delphi 10.1 Berlin build 24.0.25048.9432). Are you perhaps calling a function that scales the button and then calls another function that scales the button (or e.g. a panel it is on) too? Could you create a [MCVE]?

Comment: It doesn't do it in XE2 (I am migrating program from xe2). An XE10 simple test doesn't do it. My routines are not being called twice. Unfortunately Change scale is re-entrant and iterating, so very hard to see where the extra call is coming from, and  diff on xe2 vs xe10 vclcontrol.pas didn't show obvious difference

Comment: There is no such thing as XE10. Unless you can produce a reproducible test case, how are we going to help?

Comment: Don't be snarky David.  Sadly producing a reproducible test case, is functionally the same as finding where the problem is i.e over 5 hours of stepping through and breakpoints, well for me it is..... Someone might well have seen it before and had to fix it,

Comment: We can't possibly know whether we've seen the same thing until you produce a reproduction. Perhaps we saw a similar but different bug. Don't mistake stack overflow as an excuse not to perform basic debugging.

Comment: @HenryCrun: There is no XE10. I assume you meant, in this case, 10.1 Berlin.

Comment: OK, I can reproduce it in 10.1 Berlin for a button on a tabsheet on a TPageControl (but not for a button on, say, a panel, as I tried first). And it seems to be fixed in 10.2 Tokyo.

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to be in VCL.ComCtrls.pas, new fn `TPageControl.ChangeScale` that calls its inherited method `CustomTabsheet.ChangeScale`. So everything on a tabsheets gets `ChangeScale` twice.
Anyone know if this has changed in 10.2?

```
procedure TPageControl.ChangeScale(M, D: Integer; isDpiChange: Boolean);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  inherited ChangeScale(M, D, isDpiChange);
  for I := 0 to FPages.Count - 1 do
    TTabSheet(Fpages[I]).ChangeScale(M, D, isDpiChange);
end;
```

Example: Button 2 is on tabsheet of PageControl1.

```
unit ScaleBy1;

  interface

  uses
    Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
    Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls;

  type
    TForm1 = class(TForm)
      Button1: TButton;
      PageControl1: TPageControl;
      TabSheet1: TTabSheet;
      TabSheet2: TTabSheet;
      Button2: TButton;
      procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
      procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    private
      { Private declarations }
    public
      { Public declarations }
    end;

  var
    Form1: TForm1;

  implementation

  {$R *.dfm}

  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    ScaleBy(140,100);
  end;

  procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    ScaleBy(100,140);
  end;

  end.
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be related to the question. The question doesn't mention page controls. Why not fix the question with an edit?

Comment: Probably related to this? https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14750

Comment: Yes probably, doesn't help though since they don't show a patch.

Comment: Please fix the question. The  information in this answer belongs in the question.

Comment: At least they say it is fixed in 10.2 Tokyo.

Comment: @UweRaabe: yes, it is fixed in Tokyo.